# Update analysis results during a MachineFunctionPass (LLVM)

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, scheduling, analysis

I am pretty new to the **LLVM** project and I am trying to make a pass for my backend.
This pass aggressively *changes the basicblock*, *deletes instruction* and *reorders them*.

In parallel, this pass uses a lot of anlysis results of many Analysis Passes (such as Alias Analysis, LiveIntervals, ScalarEvolution etc.)

Does **LLVM** update results of the Analysis during runtime or is there any special keyword that *runs the analysis passes* again while running my ***MachineFunctionPass***?